# ZedGraph in C #: no point shown

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, zedgraph

i am trying ZedGraph in windows form. i imported the dll and it shows in UI designer successfully. when i compile and run the program. it pops up the zedgrah grilled view, but no points on it. could anyone help me see what was wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using ZedGraph;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void zedGraphControl1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CreateChart(zedGraphControl1);
        }
        public void CreateChart(ZedGraphControl zgc)
        {
            GraphPane myPane = zgc.GraphPane;

            // Set the title and axis labels
            myPane.Title.Text = "Line Graph with Band Demo";
            myPane.XAxis.Title.Text = "Sequence";
            myPane.YAxis.Title.Text = "Temperature, C";

            // Enter some random data values
            double[] y = { 100, 115, 75, 22, 98, 40, 10 };
            double[] y2 = { 90, 100, 95, 35, 80, 35, 35 };
            double[] y3 = { 80, 110, 65, 15, 54, 67, 18 };
            double[] x = { 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700 };

            // Fill the axis background with a color gradient
            myPane.Chart.Fill = new Fill(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 245), Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 190), 90F);

            // Generate a red curve with "Curve 1" in the legend
            LineItem myCurve = myPane.AddCurve("Curve 1", x, y, Color.Red);
            // Make the symbols opaque by filling them with white
            myCurve.Symbol.Fill = new Fill(Color.White);

            // Generate a blue curve with "Curve 2" in the legend
            myCurve = myPane.AddCurve("Curve 2", x, y2, Color.Blue);
            // Make the symbols opaque by filling them with white
            myCurve.Symbol.Fill = new Fill(Color.White);

            // Generate a green curve with "Curve 3" in the legend
            myCurve = myPane.AddCurve("Curve 3", x, y3, Color.Green);
            // Make the symbols opaque by filling them with white
            myCurve.Symbol.Fill = new Fill(Color.White);

            // Manually set the x axis range
            myPane.XAxis.Scale.Min = 0;
            myPane.XAxis.Scale.Max = 800;
            // Display the Y axis grid lines
            myPane.YAxis.MajorGrid.IsVisible = true;
            myPane.YAxis.MinorGrid.IsVisible = true;

            // Draw a box item to highlight a value range
            BoxObj box = new BoxObj(0, 100, 1, 30, Color.Empty,
                    Color.FromArgb(150, Color.LightGreen));
            box.Fill = new Fill(Color.White, Color.FromArgb(200, Color.LightGreen), 45.0F);
            // Use the BehindAxis zorder to draw the highlight beneath the grid lines
            box.ZOrder = ZOrder.E_BehindCurves;
            // Make sure that the boxObj does not extend outside the chart rect if the chart is zoomed
            box.IsClippedToChartRect = true;
            // Use a hybrid coordinate system so the X axis always covers the full x range
            // from chart fraction 0.0 to 1.0
            box.Location.CoordinateFrame = CoordType.XChartFractionYScale;
            myPane.GraphObjList.Add(box);

            // Add a text item to label the highlighted range
            TextObj text = new TextObj("Optimal\nRange", 0.95f, 85, CoordType.AxisXYScale,
                                    AlignH.Right, AlignV.Center);
            text.FontSpec.Fill.IsVisible = false;
            text.FontSpec.Border.IsVisible = false;
            text.FontSpec.IsBold = true;
            text.FontSpec.IsItalic = true;
            text.Location.CoordinateFrame = CoordType.XChartFractionYScale;
            text.IsClippedToChartRect = true;
            myPane.GraphObjList.Add(text);

            // Fill the pane background with a gradient
            myPane.Fill = new Fill(Color.WhiteSmoke, Color.Lavender, 0F);

            // Calculate the Axis Scale Ranges
            zgc.AxisChange();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving the CreateChart method call somewhere else (for example Form_Load instead of zedGraphControl1_Load)

Comment: thanks
you are right about it. should be called in the form constructor.